# Docker image for .net 5

Tags: docker, .net-5

Typically I use following images for .net core 3.1 and it works fine.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
```

I have for experimental reason started a new .net 5 project and created `dockerfile` with following

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base 
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:5.0-buster AS build
```

and have following issue:

```
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:5.0-buster                           0.2s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim                   0.2s
 => CANCELED [build 1/7] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:5.0-buster                                    0.0s
 => => resolve mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:5.0-buster                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                             0.0s
 => ERROR [base 1/2] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim                                0.0s
 => => resolve mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

As I read [here](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/1939), it is changed to:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
```

It is also mentioned on the [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-runtime/) with [more info](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/2375):

> As part of the .NET 5.0 release, all .NET Docker images (including
> .NET Core 2.1 and 3.1) have transitioned to a new set of Docker
> repositories described below. Updates will continue to be made to
> supported tags in the old repository locations for backwards
> compatibility. Please update any repository references to these new
> names. For more information see the .NET 5.0 repository rename
> announcement.

[image]

---

**EDIT:**
Image descriptions:

| Image | Comments |
| --- | --- |
| mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0 | .NET 5 multi-architecture: Supports Linux and Windows Nano Server depending on the Docker host. |
| mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 | ASP.NET Core 5.0 multi-architecture: Supports Linux and Windows Nano Server depending on the Docker host. The aspnetcore image has a few optimizations for ASP.NET Core. |
| mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim | .NET 5 runtime-only on Linux Debian distro |
| mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-nanoserver-1809 | .NET 5 runtime-only on Windows Nano Server (Windows Server version 1809) |

Image description [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/net-core-net-framework-containers/net-container-os-targets).

Answer (score 6):

You do not have to write this yourself. A quick way to go about it is to use the dockerfile generator as explained by Julio Casal in this quick tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQSuZFd01tY.

A sample code for MyApp will look like

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyApp/MyApp.csproj", "MyApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyApp/MyApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyApp"
RUN dotnet build "MyApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```